# Provisioning profile are marked as pending

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I've been using these provisioning profile for a device for at least 3-4 weeks with no problem, but now I want to add a new device but I can't download the provisioning profiles from the developer portal at www.apple.com/developer because it says that they're pending (managed by xcode). How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try deleting and recreating profiles? That could also help http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/21/xcode-5-team-provisioning-profiles/

Comment: I'm worried that if I delete the profiles I won't be able to properly recreate them.

Comment: Don't worry about it.